# Align numbers in FlexTable by decimal numbers in R

Tags: r, flextable

I want to align the numbers in columns of flextable by decimal places as shown in the image below:

Any idea to do this. I have seen to format the decimal numbers, but that is not needed.
Any help would be appreciated

[See the image below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JBMX.png)

Comment: I don't think you will get an answer. An issue is opened to get that feature: https://github.com/davidgohel/flextable/issues/278 but it's not implemented yet

Comment: @DavidGohel Yes..its not implemented yet. Thanks